# Next element vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some data that gets show like this:

```
<data 1> | <data 2> | <data 3>
<data 4> | <data 5> | <data 6>
```

What I want is this:

```
<data 1> | <data 3> | <data 5>
<data 2> | <data 4> | <data 6>
```

for up to about 5 rows.

I'm currently using an `<ul>` and the data is inseted into `<li>`'s. The `<ul>` has a width of 25% to allow for 3 of them on the same row, I just want to change the order in which they appear (they are currently being sorted by date, ascending).

Comment: please add your CSS and html

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

ul{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
width:25%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul><li>data1 |</li>
<li>data2 |</li></ul>

<ul><li>data3 |</li>
<li>data4|</li></ul>

<ul><li>data5 |</li>
<li>data6 |</li></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot move your data physically to the row in which you want it to display? For example:

- data1 |
- data3 |
- data5

- data2 |
- data4 |
- data6

You do not indicate anywhere that your data is dynamic. If it is, then maybe you should build an array before you build your unordered lists (ul) and then display according to even and odd indexes in the array. This can be done with javascript, php or numerous other languages. What is your code base?

Answer (score 0):

Tor this type of task you can use [CSS columns](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/):

```
column-count: 3;
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aw9vC/

Browser support: all modern browsers and IE10+. For IE you should make sure `LI` items has `display: inline-block` or `float: left` to allow graceful degradation to default order.